# How to filter dynamic inputs using grep() function of jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm using "grep" function of jQuery to filter the data,the below code sample works fine as the condition is static.

But  if "name" and "school" parameter has more than one value how to filter it..?, Consider i receive name & school from multiple checkbox list.Ideally i do not want to hard code

```
var students = 
[ {'id':1, 'name':'amit', 'school':'st john'},
  {'id':2, 'name':'ankit','school':'st mary'},
  {'id':3, 'name':'john', 'school':'hill school'},
  {'id':4, 'name':'matt', 'school':'st john'}];


jQuery.grep(students,function(student)
 { return  student.name =='john' && student.school=='st.john' });

//something like this is possible?
 { student.name =='john||jack||stella' && student.school=='st.john||st.mary' });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it but not quite the way you're thinking:

```
var names   = [ 'john', 'jack', 'stella' ];
var schools = [ 'st john', 'st mary' ];
var matches = jQuery.grep(students, function(student) {
    return names.indexOf(student.name)     != -1
        && schools.indexOf(student.school) != -1;
});
```

So you just need to set up your `names` and `schools` arrays based on your dynamic inputs and away you go.